# pin view to bottom of screen and ignore bottom safe area

Tags: swiftui

Layout question -  how do I setup for a view block to expand over the bottom safe area? I've looked through various sources for ignoresSafeAreas() but can't achieve quite the result I'm looking for.
I want, later, to be able to expand this view upwards but start it short. If that makes sense.

```
    var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Spacer()
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text ("Expand to fill bottom safe area ...?")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }

        .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 100)
        .background(Color.red)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Option 1

Put `ignoresSafeArea` inside `background`. This will let the red color extend over to the device edges, but the `HStack`'s position will stay the same.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text ("Expand to fill bottom safe area ...?")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            
            .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 100)
            .background(Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()) /// inside `background`
        }
    }
}
```

#### Option 2

Put `ignoresSafeArea` on the `VStack`, and everything will ignore the safe area.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text ("Expand to fill bottom safe area ...?")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            
            .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 100)
            .background(Color.red)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea() /// attached to `VStack`
    }
}
```

Result:

| Option 1 | Option 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Red color extends to bottom of screen, text stays put] | [image: Text and red color stick to the bottom of the screen] |